# JSONException during AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        String readMyJSON = readMyJSON();
                try {
                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readMyJSON);                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is not working, during `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readMyJSON);`, JSONException occurs. Could somebody tell me where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Method I use:

```
   public String readMyJSON() 
   {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android");
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
            Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
      }
```

This method seems to be allright.

Comment: What do you get for output from readMyJSON()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the response from twitter is not an JSON array, so you get an exception. If you want the array of results, do the following:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
JSONArray results = object.getJSONArray("results");
```

I suggest you read the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). Specifically, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search.

Comment: I wanted to do this for the purpose of learning how to work with JSON. I used this search result only as an example. It seems that it´s working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("["+readMyJSON+"]");
```

I hope it should work.